# .htaccess Replace a word and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, replace

I need to redirect `http://example.com/view-abc-def.html` to `http://example.com/view/abc-def.html`. In order to do that I used,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)view-(.*)$ /$1view/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This works perfectly until there are no other occurrences of **view-** in the URL. But unfortunately, if the URL is like `http://example.com/view-abc-view-def.html` it will end up in a 404.

So I tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/view-(.*)$ /$1view/$2 [R=301,L]
```

But in this case, it won't change anything in the URL. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your existing rule with this one:

```
RewriteRule (^|.*?/)view-(.*)$ /$1view/$2 [R=302,L,NC]
```

Change from `R=302` to `R=301` once you verify it to be working.

Answer (score 1):

You can first eliminate all internal `-view-`s and then do the actual redirect

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-view-(.*)$ $1-$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/view-(.*)$ /$1/view/$2 [R,L]
```

When everything works as you expect, you can change `R` to `R=301`.

*Never* test with `301` enabled, see this answer
[Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)
for details.